# Spring MVC returning XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException when trying to use mvc:resources or mvc:default-servlet-handler

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I just started to study Spring using the 3.0.0 RELEASE version, and when I declare the tag **mvc:resources** or **mvc:default-servlet-handler** the server returns the XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException, telling me that it couldn't find the tag's reference.

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are declaring them in the bean configuration file? If so, what is the xml namespace declaration?

Comment: To get better answers, you should post the config file.

Comment: Hi everyone, the code is about big, so I hosted it in the following link: http://sdrv.ms/QILlIp

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some work I discovered the answer for my question. Inside the header os the spring-context.xml I opened the url link http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc and then selected the **spring-mvc-3.0.xsd** file, in this case [this link](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd).

After use the browser's search for **default-servlet-handler**, I've found it's declaration in the file, and saw that the class that was needed for this tag was **org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler**.

I found some references in the web, telling that this class was implemented in the Spring 3.0.5, and I was using 3.0.0. So, I've downloaded the right version of the framework, replaced it in my classpath, and everything worked right.